How to create Django model of 10 rows and 10 columns for one id(primary)
wanted like this 10x10
I'm attempting to develop a 10Rows and 10Columns (textfield) model in Django for one user so that he can add data via a form. Is there a way to make it dynamic? In the future, I may need to add 50 rows and 50 columns.
I try to do manually its so long to do

imageNo_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
imageNo_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
imageNo_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    imageNo_4 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    imageNo_5 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    imageNo_6 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    imageNo_7 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    imageNo_8 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    imageNo_9 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    imageNo_10 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc_1 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc_2 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc_3 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc_4 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc_5 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc_6 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc_7 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc_8 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc_9 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc_10 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
.
.
.
img_alt_1 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_alt_2 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_alt_3 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_alt_4 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_alt_5 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_alt_6 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_alt_7 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_alt_8 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_alt_9 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
img_alt_10 = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I found answer:

for rowthirty in range(1, 31):
  locals()[f"imageNo_{rowthirty}"] = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
  locals()[f"img_desc_{rowthirty}"] = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
  locals()[f"img_alt_{rowthirty}"] = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I understand what you are trying to do, but I think a better solution is to use more Models.
for example, you can made the Model "Image" and have only 3 fields:
image = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
img_desc = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
img_alt = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)

Then another Model (Join Table) between User and Image:
class UserImage(models.Model):
    image= models.ForeignKey("Image", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user= models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Another tip: Charfield contains at least 255 characters, so use TextField if you want more.
